# Set Command in for-loop

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop, set

I'm writing a script where I put local users in an array and use them in a for loop while parsing with set to display the last command information. I'm able to parse with just the commands inside of the "do" section successfully if run in a script by itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Automation Project (Khal)
#Author: Zacquille Joseph
#Version 1.2


#Get Users on System
user=$(getent passwd {1000..60000} | cut -d: -f1  )
#Puts all Users into Array
array=($user)

for item in ${array[*]}
do
set $(last | grep -w $item | head -n 1 )

echo
echo $*
echo "Name: $1"
echo "Date: $4 $5 $6"
echo "Time: $7"
echo "Status: $7 $8 $9 ${10}"
echo

done
```

I expect to only have an output of

```
mary pts/2 X.X.X.X Wed Apr 17 15:31 - 15:36 (00:04)
Name: mary
Date: Wed Apr 17
Time: 15:31
Status: 15:31 - 15:36 (00:04)


zac pts/0 X.X.X.X Tue Apr 30 14:10 still logged in
Name: zac
Date: Tue Apr 30
Time: 14:10
Status: 14:10 still logged in
```

instead I'm getting that combined with this:

```
BASH=/bin/bash
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:complete_fullquote:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
BASH_SOURCE=([0]="./cst1.sh")
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="4" [2]="19" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.4.19(1)-release'
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=1004
GROUPS=()
.....
```

FYI:

```
last | grep -w zac | head -n 1
```

Will return this:

```
zac      pts/0        X.X.X.X  Tue Apr 30 14:10   still logged in
```

Running this:

```
set $(last | head -n 10 | tail -n 1)

echo
echo $*
echo "Name: $1"
echo "Date: $4 $5 $6"
echo "Time: $7"
echo "Status: $7 $8 $9 ${10}"
echo
```

will return:

```
ubuntu pts/4 X.X.X.X Thu Apr 18 22:47 - 01:01 (02:13)
Name: ubuntu
Date: Thu Apr 18
Time: 22:47
Status: 22:47 - 01:01 (02:13)
```

Comment: That seems like the output of `set` without any argument. Make sure the `last | ...` command substitution returns something.

Comment: Are you sure each user has logged in at least once?

Answer (score 1):

try using another array instead of set command, eg :

```
arr2=($(last | grep -w $item | head -n 1 ))

echo
echo $*
echo "Name: ${arr2[0]} "
echo "Date: ${arr2[3]} ${arr2[4]}  ${arr2[5]} "
echo "Time:  ${arr2[6]}"
echo "Status: ${arr2[6]} ${arr2[7]}  ${arr2[8]}  ${arr2[9]}"
echo
```

Comment: `read -r -a arr2 < <(last | grep -w "$item")` is considerably more robust. That way you don't have a name of `*` replaced with a list of filenames, and you don't need the `head` (since `read` only reads one line anyhow).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT! One of the users never logged on but was created. For the purpose of my script all the users have to logon. Ideally i just replaced `$item` with each user and running the script (luckily we don't have to much users), then found that one specific user who never logged on gave that large output.